# How to customize the registration form in sylius?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3, sylius

All in the title, how to customize the registration form in sylius ?

There are two base forms, one from FOSUserBundle and second one from Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle, which one to extend and to configure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius [extends the FOSUserBundle registration form](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/1e040afb4e31ee9eac836f697795d6f51f731d3c/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php#L17), by adding the fields for the user's first name and last name and removing the `username` field.

This is then [registered as a service and tagged](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/8270d05f29ca30d9144dc80c8ff8083e72ac572b/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L124) with `sylius_user_registration`. This is the same value that's returned in the `RegistrationFormType::getName()` method.

In order to override the forms in the FOSUserBundle in general, you'll simply [declare the form type definition with the value the form is tagged with](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/d53a4ead3a00307e465128f9957e4f64a6540c9b/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/main.yml#L75), in this case, `sylius_user_registration`.

If you wish to extend the form yourself, just follow the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Demo's registration form](http://demo.sylius.org/register/) has `fos_user_registration_form[firstName]`, etc., for input names.

So, it appears that FOSUserBundle is taking care of the registration form.